# PHP insert into database in a loop

Tags: php

I am trying to insert multiple records in a for loop like so:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
mysqli_select_db($connection, "database");

for ($i = 1; $i <= $_POST['people']; $i++) {

    $stmt = "";

    if ($stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO `table` (firstname, lastname, email, rsvp) VALUES (?,?,?,?)")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('ssss', "James", "Smith", "smith@abc.com", "yes");
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
}

mysql_close($connection);
```

But its not inserting, I put in an echo at the beginning of the loop and it only echos once. Please help.

Comment: Your code may contain syntax errors. 
Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: what is the value of `$_POST['people']`

Comment: the value of people is 2

Comment: "the value of people is 2" spookey

Comment: The only way it isn't going to finish its iterations, is if there is a fatal error, or $_POST['people']=1. Put ini_set('display_errors', '1'); at the top of the file to make sure there are no error.s

Comment: `mysqli_stmt::bind_param()` takes variable references as its arguments - it won't work with scalar values like you used. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php As suggested, turn on `display_errors` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. You should see PHP complain abut this.

Comment: Did my answer help at all?

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning all of your customer data to variables first, like so:

```
$firstname = 'James';
$lastname  = 'Smith';
$email     = 'smith@abc.com';
$rsvp      = 'yes';

$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $firstname, $lastname, $email, $rsvp);
```